# Is there a way to retrieve the notes object from Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am fetching the refunds data from api.stripe to BQ.
Besides the charge info itself I also need the Timeline notes, since there is the order id linked to the specific refund (I can find them in the Dashboard [https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments/{id}](https://dashboard.stripe.com/payments/%7Bid%7D)).
The problem is that I don't find this object anywhere, and I don't find any reference in the documentation on which endpoint contains it.

On the browser I find this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "note_...",
      "object": "note",
      "created": ####,
      "created_by": {
        "id": "usr_...",
        "object": "user",
        "email": "...",
        "name": "..."
      },
      "edited_by": null,
      "from_email": null,
      "mentions": [],
      "parent": "ch_...",
      "pinned": false,
      "source": "dashboard",
      "text": "THE ID I NEED TO FETCH"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false
}
```

That text from the object note is what I need to fetch.
I've looked into https://.stripe.com/charges, also payment_intents, refunds, and I tried to expand all available fields on these but I don't seem to be able to find the note object anywhere.
In which Endpoint is this object? How can I fetch this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the notes that can be added in the Stripe Dashboard (as in the screenshot below), then you can't fetch these via the API. They're only available in the Dashboard.

[image]

That being said, you can use `metadata` to leave notes on most Stripe objects, and then retrieve them via the API at a later time: https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata